# How do I link with gcc on MinWG

Tags: gcc, mingw

Is this syntax incorrect?

```
C:\Users\Brett\Compilers>gcc -I MinGW\include -l MinGW\lib\libgdi32.a -o hello
    world helloworld.c
```

The directory's are all fine, I mist be including and linking in the wrong order or something?

Here is the output:

```
c:/users/Brett/compilers/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../../mingw
2/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lMinGW\lib\libgdi32.a
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: I think I figured it out. You don't need the -l

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for `-l` switch is the library name without `lib` prefix and without the extension. If it cannot be found, it's directory should be given with `-L` option. So I would write:

```
gcc -I MinGW\include -L MinGW\lib -lgdi32 -o helloworld helloworld.c
```

Maybe `-L` is not needed, maybe you also need `-mwindows` to tell the linker you want windows app. To specify a library file explicitly, give it without any letter option, like this:

```
gcc -I MinGW\include MinGW\lib\libgdi32.a -o helloworld helloworld.c
```

Here is the gcc reference: [linking options](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html).