# Undefined reference to __imp_Rectangle in C++

Tags: c++, linker

I have been having trouble compiling some code in C++.

Code:

```
#include <windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc( HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM );

int WINAPI WinMain( HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR szCmdLine, int nShowCmd )
{

    static char name[] = "My Application";
    WNDCLASSEX wc;
    HWND hwnd;
    MSG Msg;

    // Step 1: Registering the Window Class
    wc.cbSize = sizeof( WNDCLASSEX );
    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon( NULL, IDI_APPLICATION );
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor( NULL, IDC_ARROW );
    wc.hbrBackground = ( HBRUSH ) ( COLOR_WINDOW + 1 );
    wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName = name;
    wc.hIconSm = LoadIcon( NULL, IDI_APPLICATION );

    if ( !RegisterClassEx( & wc ) )
    {

        MessageBox( NULL, "Window Registration Failed!", "Registration Failure", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK );

        return 0;

    }

    // Step 2: Creating the Window
    hwnd = CreateWindowEx( WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, name, "My First Window", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 400, 400, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL );

    ShowWindow( hwnd, nShowCmd );
    UpdateWindow( hwnd );

    // Step 3: The Message Loop
    while( GetMessage( & Msg, NULL, 0, 0 ) > 0 )
    {

        TranslateMessage( & Msg );

        DispatchMessage( & Msg );

    }

    return ( int )Msg.wParam;

}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc( HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam )
{

    HDC hdc;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    RECT rect;

    switch( msg )
    {

        case WM_PAINT:

            hdc = BeginPaint( hwnd, & ps );

            GetClientRect( hwnd, & rect );

            Rectangle( hdc, rect.right / 2 - 50, rect.bottom / 2 - 20, rect.right / 2 + 50, rect.bottom / 2 + 20 );

            DrawText( hdc, "Hello World!", -1, & rect, DT_SINGLELINE | DT_CENTER | DT_VCENTER );

            EndPaint( hwnd, & ps );

            break;

        case WM_CLOSE:

            DestroyWindow( hwnd );

            break;

        case WM_DESTROY:

            PostQuitMessage( 0 );

            break;

    }

    return DefWindowProc( hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam );

}
```

The tutorial I am following says that it compiles correctly with no problems, but this is what my compiler looks like:

```
NPP_EXEC: "Compile C++ File"
NPP_SAVE: G:\C++\src\Win32\Hello World! Window.cpp
g++ -o "G:\C++\src\Win32\Hello World! Window" "G:\C++\src\Win32\Hello World! Window.cpp" -static
Process started >>>
C:\Users\Braeden\AppData\Local\Temp\cc3N4Ls1.o:Hello World! Window.cpp:(.text+0x29b): undefined reference to `__imp_Rectangle'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
<<< Process finished.
================ READY ================
```

I am not using any popular IDE. I am using Notepad++ as a text editor and a MinGW distro as my compiler. I am on Win7 x64. Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: linker cannot find `Rectangle` definition

Comment: You need to link against gdi32.lib. I don't know how to do this with gcc. You will probably need to have the Windows SDK installed if you don't already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Rectangle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162898.aspx) is provided by `Gdi32.dll`. You should be [linking against](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12671505/how-do-i-link-with-gcc-on-minwg) `Gdi32.lib`.

Comment: OK, Thanks for the link, I got the problem sorted out! I had to use the -mwindows option to include all the important dll's, including Gdi32.dll. Thanks!